# How to change QML TextField text property using key events generated from C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a QML LineEdit like:

```
TextField
{
  id: testEdit
  text: "0"
  Keys.onPressed:
  {
    console.log("Press = " + event.key)
    console.log("Current text is " + text)
  }
  Keys.onReleased:
  {
    console.log("Release = " + event.key)
    console.log("Current text is " + text)
  }
}
```

I want to change its text property ***by simulating key events***. So I have C++ object (eventHandler) exposed to QML generating key events:

```
void normalKeyPress(QQuickItem *receiver, QString keys)
{
  receiver->forceActiveFocus();

  QKeySequence keysSeq = QKeySequence(keys);
  for (auto idx = 0; idx < keysSeq.count(); ++idx)
  {
    auto keyCode = keysSeq[idx];
    auto keyEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, keyCode, Qt::NoModifier);
    auto keyEventSent = QApplication::sendEvent(receiver, keyEvent);

    keyEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, keyCode, Qt::NoModifier);
    keyEventSent = QApplication::sendEvent(receiver, keyEvent);
  }
}
```

Now in QML, when I do:

```
testEdit.forceActiveFocus()
eventHandler.normalKeyPress(testEdit, "4")
eventHandler.normalKeyPress(testEdit, "Enter")
```

I get the following output:

```
qml: Press = 52
qml: Current text is 0
qml: Release = 52
qml: Current text is 0
qml: Press = 16777221
qml: Current text is 0
qml: Release = 16777221
qml: Current text is 0
```

So key events are correctly received by the QML LineEdit.

**But why text property is not updated accordingly?**

**UPDATE #1:** if I use a `TextInput` instead of a `TextField`, then it works as expected.

Comment: Did you create LineEdit yourself? I can't find the documentation on the Qt website.

Comment: @JeffreyvandeGlind: oups, wrong copy-paste-edit. With a TextField, you get the same results. I edited my question. Nice catch, thanks!

Comment: Does the `TextField` has active focus ? Make sure to call `forceActiveFocus` or at least set `focus` to `true`

Comment: @GrecKo: I am actually calling forceActiveFocus in QML and in C++ (just to be sure). As you can see in the output, it is correctly receiving the events.  But its text property is not updated accordingly (while it should right?).

Comment: I have same problem: key events are sent - `text` property not changed. Any solution found? Can't change to `TextInput` for now.

Comment: Found some info here: https://forum.qt.io/post/150993 - need to use `receiver->window()->sendEvent()` however it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your code, I think the solution in adding `setProperty()` method to your `reciever`. So your code will be:

```
void normalKeyPress(QQuickItem *receiver, QString keys)
{
  receiver->forceActiveFocus();
  receiver->setProperty("text", keys);

  <...>
}
```

Comment: You sending event and in qml you just catch another event without setting a property as text. You just can set `keyCode` as `text` property in handler, but it will be code, not name of a key. Or you can catch other signal by qml which will be send from `normalKeyPress` method.

Comment: This is for test purposes. So I need to send events to my QML components. Those must react as if I typed "4" in it. I just don't only want to set the value.